# Can wine gone bad be bad for you?

Tags: food-safety, vinegar, wine

Unfortunately, wine will eventually go bad. The time this takes can vary from a few years to many decades, but most wines eventually will get there; and things can always be sped up by improper storage. The result of this is mostly associated with loss of good taste and / or development of bad taste.

My question is if that's all, or if wine can also develop properties that can be bad for your health (apart from the health risks already associated with normal wine)? E.g. is it possible that wine gone bad can give you food poisoning or similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wine will eventually turn into vinegar.  So, other than having a really icky taste by itself (unless you like drinking vinegar :)), it isn't bad for your health and you can cook with it.

Comment: This is not vinegar-like, this is plain vinegar. Very good one indeed.

Comment: We've about a cup left from half a bottle of a red wine that went to a particularly pleasing vinegar on us a couple of year ago. It's served in salad dressing and soups of every description since then. Yum!